# pyarrow serialize pandas df with nullable Integer type

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

I would like to make use of the new nullable dtypes in `pandas 1.0`. Has anybody had success with serializing a pd.DataFrame containing a nullable integer column using pyarrow?

The resources I have used so far are documented in the code block. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow  # version 0.16
import pyarrow as pa

# workaround suggested in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-5379
pd.arrays.IntegerArray.__arrow_array__ = lambda self, type: pyarrow.array(self._data, mask=self._mask, type=type)

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2])
df = df.convert_dtypes()

# following https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html#serializing-pandas-objects
context = pa.default_serialization_context()
context.serialize(df)
```

Error message

```
SerializationCallbackError: pyarrow does not know how to serialize objects of type <class 'pandas.core.arrays.integer.IntegerArray'>.
```

Comment: Would you like to open a JIRA issue about this? https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: xref https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7883